# what does this skype message mean?

Tags: 17.10, snap

```
android@android:~$ sudo snap install skype
error: This revision of snap "skype" was published using classic confinement and thus may perform
       arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to,
       which may put your system at risk.

       If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including --classic.
```

what does this mean? Could someone elaborate on this.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the skype is not yet strictly confined. To install it, for now you will have to run:

```
sudo snap install skype --classic
```

Here you can find an explanation about confinement in snaps:
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/devmode-strict-and-classic-explained-in-two-minutes/391